# Potted poinciana suggestions

Tags: houseplants, plant-health

Recently I discovered this wonderful tree and bought some seeds hoping to grow a few of them, although the climate I am living in doesn't offer a warm weather all year round.

I have been seeing the leaves turning yellow. I read here and there about overwatering, which I think was the problem so I've started reducing the amount of water they receive.

What concerns me is that 2 of them don't look healthy. For one of them, the younger branches are turning yellow, and for the other, the leaves and branches seem to wither.

[image: poinciana]
[image: poinciana2]